# Unknown usb error number -32 in dmesg output

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

if i run `sudo dmesg | grep usb` i get a line in the output with the following error message:

```
device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

I could not ind any documentation about this error. Can you anybody guide me into the right direction?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: A bit of context would be helpful:

    $ sudo dmesg | grep -B5 -A5 -i usb